# What are the default knitr fonts (an explanatory image was added) in R?

Tags: r, fonts, knitr

I see 6 different fonts in knitr outputs, inter alia, see the following image. I gave them one by one.
What are these fonts exactly (complete name with font family)?

....Example......*Font's Usage*........Font....
1. library    *Red Function*             ??
2. readxl *Black Argument*           ??
3. paketi *Purple Comment*    mwa_cmitt10  R,G,B=173,153,182??
4. Users *Blue String*                    ??
5. by   *Green "argument="*          ??
6. 115  *Magenta value*               ??

[image]

Comment: Given the LaTeX connection, I've always assumed they're Computer Modern. [See here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234786/120019) for how to change the font family, if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output in the question looks like it comes from an RNW document. Reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
library(knitr) # useless stuff
var <- as.numeric("42")
var <- as.character(var)
names(var) <- rep(x = var, times = 1)
@
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

The font used depends on the setup of the LaTeX document, but as [alistaire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090210/what-are-the-default-knitr-fonts-an-explanatory-image-was-added-in-r#comment69386985_41090210) already pointed out, by default it is "Computer Modern". On top of this, come keywords are colored differently or typeset in italics, according to the definitions that `knitr` adds into the generated TEX file:

```
\newcommand{\hlnum}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.686,0.059,0.569}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstr}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.192,0.494,0.8}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlcom}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.678,0.584,0.686}{\textit{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlopt}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.345,0.345,0.345}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwa}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.161,0.373,0.58}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwb}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.353,0.396}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.333,0.667,0.333}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.737,0.353,0.396}{\textbf{#1}}}%
```

These formatting commands are used for syntax highlighting in the code output:

```
\begin{alltt}
\hlkwd{library}\hlstd{(knitr)} \hlcom{# useless stuff}
\hlstd{var} \hlkwb{<-} \hlkwd{as.numeric}\hlstd{(}\hlstr{"42"}\hlstd{)}
\hlstd{var} \hlkwb{<-} \hlkwd{as.character}\hlstd{(var)}
\hlkwd{names}\hlstd{(var)} \hlkwb{<-} \hlkwd{rep}\hlstd{(}\hlkwc{x} \hlstd{= var,} \hlkwc{times} \hlstd{=} \hlnum{1}\hlstd{)}
\end{alltt}
```

Comment: `[rgb]{0.678,0.584,0.686}` seem to correspond to R,G,B=173,153,182. Many thanks for the helpful answer.

Comment: @ErdoganCEVHER Welcome. Your "RGB conversion" is almost correct. In `[rgb]{0.678,0.584,0.686}`, values are between 0 and 1, so you have to multiply by 255 to get RGB values between 0 and 255. Example:  0.584 implies 149 (not 153).